# Good solution for Emacs key bindings in Xcode

Tags: xcode, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

So i'm using the solution that overwrites the DefaultKeyBindning.dict file provided by
https://gist.github.com/smilingpoplar/1728384 to have some basic Emacs functionality in Xcode.
However, C-x C-s does not work properly when trying to save. Mapping it in the Xcode preferences is also impossible as I am allowed either ^x or ^s but not both .

Does anyone have a better solution to Emacs emulation in Xcode or a way to get the save working via C-x C-s ?( which is in muscle memory now every time I want to save a change to the source I'm writing).

Comment: Anyone wondering why "invalid chars" keep appearing, you have muscle-memory-autosave enabled. (aka. you're hitting `C-x C-s` without thinking and it's inserting an invisible `^S` into the file open in XCode.)

Answer (score 6):

Karabiner can allow you to do that.
https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Input "control x prefix" in the search field and tick "Enable Control+X" like this.

[image: Karabiner]